# Gain-Bandwidth Confusion

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image]

Hi, I saw this online and I'm a bit confused why they chose B as the correct answer.

My answer was:
The DC voltage gain is 20dB, so -3dB frequency will occur at 17dB gain. 17dB in normal gain is 7.07945.

GBP = (Gain)(BW)

BW = GBP/Gain

BW = 1MHz/7.07945 = 141253.7545Hz

**This is option D.**

Comment: It can be confusing. First off, the -3 dB corner is for *power*. Not voltage. And while it is very, very common to see "voltage gain" in dB, the very idea of it derives from a hidden assumption that power is proportional to voltage-squared. So, 20 dB of voltage gain implies 10 dB of power gain implies A=10 for the purposes of the gain-bandwidth spec. Of course, that specification also is taken to imply single-pole behavior and the assumption (not always true) that an opamp's gain-bandwidth product is independent of the designed gain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Gain" in the equation:
$$GBP = Gain \times BW$$
is a linear gain, not dB. You can't plug dB directly into that equation.

---

Furthermore, bandwidth (in most cases) is defined as the frequency where the output drops by 3dB so it's already accounted for. It's part of the definition. You don't need to account for the -3dB a second time.

---

20dB is the open loop gain of the op-amp at DC.

1MHz is the GBP which means that it is the frequency when the open-loop gain of the op-amp drops to one.

Notice that I did not mention 3dB anywhere. That's because is not part of the definitions of either of these things (sort of, as you can see from the above equation there is some relation)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the gain of 10 as a constant horizontal line on the gain/frequency plot (this constant gain is referred to as the noise gain). This constant line will cross the open loop response at 100kHz so the bandwidth is 100kHz. It is the noise gain which determines bandwidth and the noise gain is 10 :

Bandwidth = GBW/(Noise Gain)

For a purely resistive feedback network, noise gain is a constant and is equal to:

Noise Gain = 1/B = (R1+R2)/R1 This is true for both inverting and non-inverting amplifiers.

The frequency at which the true closed loop response is down 3dB is the same frequency at which the constant noise gain response meets the open loop response. At this frequency the closed loop response will still be a little way from the open loop  response curve.

So the answer is correct it is B.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the gain in the pass band of the system which is 20 dB, not 17 dB.

Comment: Why is that? Isn't it called the -3dB frequency because it's 3dB below the DC gain?

Comment: @AlfroJang80 Yes, but remember that equation is not an equation that graphs out gain vs frequency. You don't just plug in a frequency and out pops the gain at that frequency. That's a bode plot. This isn't a bode plot or a bode plot equation.

Comment: Make this a better answer by explaining **why** you would need to use 20 dB instead of 17 dB. The reason is simple: The GBW = Gain x BW formula applies to a (theoretical) "straight lines" Bode plot. These do not have a -3 dB point, the gain is flat over frequency until the transition frequency and then drops down with 20dB/decade. In the real world that's not possible, the transition is more gradual and the gain will have dropped 3 dB at the transition point.